# REGEX Pattern For URL Validation

Tags: php, regex, validation, url

I'm using this PHP function for validate an URL.

```
$url = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-\/\.\:]/", "", trim($url));
$url = preg_replace('%^(?!https?://www\.).*%', 'http://www\.$0', $url);
```

But, this isn't  perfect for me. I want to this controls :

1 - Is it starting with **http://** or **https://** ? If not, add **http** (or **https**)

2 - If it hasn't subdomain and if it hasn't **www** , add . But if it has subdomain don't add **www**.

Examples :

```
example.com
CONVERT -> http://www.example.com

www.example.com
CONVERT -> http://www.example.com

subdomain.example.com
CONVERT -> http://subdomain.example.com

http://subdomain.example.com
CONVERT -> http://subdomain.example.com
```

So, I need improve my REGEX pattern. But I can't. How can I use this?

Comment: The first regex will strip too many valid charactes from any existing url path and fail on any newfangled `http://[::1]/~user/a+b?x=1#2`.

Comment: possible duplicate of [regex problem with url](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2987263/regex-problem-with-url)

Answer (score 0):

Remove the `www\.` from the second regex. This would make it work on the subdomain examples.

If you want to make it more intelligent, use an `if` and a second regex to check for `^(\w+://)?\w+\.\w+$` prior prefixing it with http:// or an extra www.

Comment: how can i use 2nd regex with PHP ?

Comment: preg_match("^(\w+://)?\w+\.\w+$", $url) ?

Comment: needs regex enclosures, but yes