# Finding Subdomain And Adding WWW with REGEX

Tags: php, regex, subdomain, preg-replace

I'm validating and adding **http** (or **https**) to my URL variable with this code :

```
$url = preg_replace("/[^A-Za-z0-9-\/\.\:]/", "", trim($url));
$url = preg_replace('%^(?!https?://).*%', 'http://$0', $url);
```

But this isn't enough for me. I need one more step , too . I have to check subdomain. If there isn't any subdomain add **www**.

For example if there isn't any subdomain and
(after this 2 **preg_replace()**) if $url is : **http://example.com** , convert to http://**WWW**.example.com. If $url is : **http://www.example.com**, don't touch.

(with preg_replace please)

**IN SUMMARY** if $url hasn't subdomain and www , add **www** .

Comment: i'm always answering other questions.

Comment: possible duplicate of [REGEX Pattern For URL Validation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4636143/regex-pattern-for-url-validation)

Comment: for the most part people figure, if he won't "accept" any answers, why bother answering the question.

Comment: @mario,i look at this post before create this post. But it's not duplicate with this question . @dqhendricks, thank you, but my other questions hasn't accepted answer and can't solve my problem :/

Comment: Do you have access to the web server configuration? This would easier and quicker to implement there

Answer (score 0):

may be easier to use php's url parser.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.parse-url.php

Comment: you can break up an url into its parts, then reassemble after edits.

Comment: Thanks, but i can't find subdomain with **parse_url()** . It gives me host with subdomain. I have to use **explode(".", $parsed);** etc.

Comment: explode as you stated, then if the array is longer than 2, the first item in the array is the subdomain.

Answer (score 0):

I got this:

```
$url = 'http://teknoblogo.com';
$host = parse_url($url, PHP_URL_HOST);
$arr = explode('.', $host);

echo http_build_url($url,
    array(
        'host' => !preg_match('/^www\d*\.$/i', $arr[0]) && count($arr) <= 2 ? 'www.' . $host : $host
    )
);
```

See also:

- [parse_url()](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.parse-url.php)
- [http_build_url()](https://www.php.net/manual/fr/function.http-build-url.php)

Answer (score 0):

Without TLD lookup tables, the only way I imagine you can do this is if you know your domain already:

```
$domain = 'example.com';

$url = preg_replace('~^(https?://)(' . preg_quote($domain, '~') . ')(.*)~i', '$1www.$2$3');
```